# Is there a way to launch gedit in fullscreen mode?

Tags: gedit, fullscreen

Is there a command I can run to launch gedit in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 7):

You can use Compiz, in particular you have to activate "Window Rules" plugin and in "Full Screen" field you write class=Gedit. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

There's a plugin for that. See: http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gedit-list/2007-March/msg00038.html

Comment: Unfortunately the link in the thread is dead.

Comment: Here you go: https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Gedit/PluginsLists?action=show&redirect=Gedit%2FPlugins

Comment: great thanks: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/PluginsLists , but there is not fullscreen plugin there. There are interesting plugins though.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do this.

Gedit can be opened with the `gedit` command. If we look at [man gedit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/gedit.1.html), there is no option to launch full screen.

You can launch Gedit with the `gedit` command and then press F11 when it has opened but there is no  command to automate this operation.